# Submit a form instantly after it's been printed

Tags: php, http, redirect, post, get

I'm building a web application where I need GET and POST variables at the same time. The get variable would hold the date, and according to that change the orders listed. POST variables are used to submit form data to the database (I have the output and the input on the same page).

Since only one HTTP method can be used at one time, I figured that I need to use POST in the following fashion to be able to read both variables:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?date=foo"></form>
```

If no date is set, this is how I set the date as today's date:

```
if(!isset($_GET["date"])) {
        header("location: index.php?date=". date('Y-m-d'));
    }
```

..but this redirect uses GET, so that's not an option.

I tried the following:

```
if(!isset($_GET["date"])) {
        echo '
            <form method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"].'?date='.date("Y-m-d").'"></form>
        ';
    }
```

This would be OK, but the form needs to behave as a redirect, so after echoing out, it needs to be submitted automatically.

How can I achieve this?

I'm also open to suggestions for achieving this functionality in other ways if possible.

Comment: javascript / jquery isn't an option?

Comment: if there is no alternative, then it has to be, but I want to minimize client side code, since it's already JS-heavy.

Comment: unfortunately there isn't an alternative, at least not that i know of :/

Comment: Sorry, I don not understand the flow of action here. If I had to do it, I'd prepare the form based on the $_GET-Params, then have the user fill in the form and SUBMIT it with a $_POST-Request to a URL which would re-use the old $_GET-Variables (or, write the $_GET-Stuff to a hidden form-field). So I do not exactly understand the problem...(why should a form "submit automatically?" The user should trigger that...)

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript maybe something like this:

Give the form a name:

```
if(!isset($_GET["date"])) {
        echo '
            <form name="MyForm" method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"].'?date='.date("Y-m-d").'"></form>
        ';
    }
```

and then you could with javascript simply submit the form like:

```
document.MyForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript in my opinion:

```
 <form name="MyForm" method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"]?>?date='<?=(isset($_GET['date'])) ? $_GET['date'] : date("Y-m-d")?>"></form>
```

It puts the date in the URL. If $_GET['date'] indeed is set, it will set $_GET['date'] as date. Otherwise it will give the current date.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: he wants the form to submit automatically, which is - in my opinion - not possible with php

Comment: True, but for placing the right date he doesn't need javascript.